# atomエディターのwindows版で「alt」でメニューが選択できない

Tags: windows, atom-editor

タイトルのとうりの現象です
一般的なwindowsのアプリと同じようにキーボードでメニューバーの操作を行いたい

具体的には、以下の操作が行いたい。
１．編集エリアにフォーカスがあるときに、「alt」を押すとメニューバーの「ファイル」が選択された状態になってほしい。
２．１の状態からは、上下左右の矢印キーでメニューバーの操作を行いたい。
    メニューバーの横の選択（ファイルから編集への移動も）矢印キーで操作したいです。

理由
私は、ALSで四肢に障害があるためオペレートナビでパソコンを操作しています。
なるべく操作を統一したいと考えました。

ita_3yさんに誤解させてしまいました。

Answer (score 2):

`alt + key`でメニューを表示したいという意図だという前提での記載です（`alt + f`でFile等）。

FileとHelpはファイル内にカーソルが当たっていない状態（タイトルバーやツリービューの余白を選択）でないと表示されないようですが、それ以外は普通に動作すると思います。

`alt`を押すと各メニューの文字に下線が表示されるので、それが対象のキーです。
e.g.
alt + f:File
alt + i:Find

また、表示されたメニューツリーの中で下線が表示されているものは、当該キーを押下すれば実行できます。
e.g.
n:New File
o:Open File

下線が表示されていないものを実行できるようにしたいのであれば、SettingsのKeybindingsを見てみると良いのではないでしょうか（実行できるようにできるかはわかりません）。